# Python h2o generates Error: Caught exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: python, nullpointerexception, h2o, automl

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import h2o

h2o.init(nthreads = 5)
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[12,3,4,5,45,6,45,7,4,2],
                      'col2': [12,3,1,23,43,1,3,12,32,1],
                      'y':[0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0]})
my_df_h2o = h2o.H2OFrame(my_df)
aml = h2o.automl.H2OAutoML(max_runtime_secs=30, seed=123)
aml.train(x=['col1', 'col2'], y='y', training_frame=my_df_h2o)
```

it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\user_data\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3441, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-9-031544adf3aa>", line 1, in <module>
    aml.train(x=['col1', 'col2'], y='y', training_frame=my_df_h2o)
  File "D:\user_data\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\h2o\automl\autoh2o.py", line 557, in train
    resp = self._build_resp = h2o.api('POST /99/AutoMLBuilder', json=automl_build_params)
  File "D:\user_data\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\h2o\h2o.py", line 113, in api
    return h2oconn.request(endpoint, data=data, json=json, filename=filename, save_to=save_to)
  File "D:\user_data\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\connection.py", line 481, in request
    return self._process_response(resp, save_to)
  File "D:\user_data\Program_Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\h2o\backend\connection.py", line 823, in _process_response
    raise H2OServerError("HTTP %d %s:\n%s" % (status_code, response.reason, data))
h2o.exceptions.H2OServerError: HTTP 500 Server Error:
Server error java.lang.NullPointerException:
  Error: Caught exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
  Request: None
```

The h2o server seems to be running just fine. I am not sure how to troubleshoot.

**UPDATE**

As per suggestion below here are the log (available from web gui). This only partial log file as full log did not fit:

```
08-31 10:50:23.742 127.0.0.1:54321       20836        main  INFO water.default: H2O started in 5837ms
08-31 10:50:23.742 127.0.0.1:54321       20836        main  INFO water.default: 
08-31 10:50:23.743 127.0.0.1:54321       20836        main  INFO water.default: Open H2O Flow in your web browser: http://127.0.0.1:54321
08-31 10:50:23.743 127.0.0.1:54321       20836        main  INFO water.default: 
08-31 10:50:23.820 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: GET /3/Metadata/schemas/CloudV3, parms: {}
08-31 10:50:23.847 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: Locking cloud to new members, because water.api.schemas3.MetadataV3
08-31 10:50:23.984 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-12  INFO water.default: GET /3/Metadata/schemas/H2OErrorV3, parms: {}
08-31 10:50:23.995 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-13  INFO water.default: GET /3/Metadata/schemas/H2OModelBuilderErrorV3, parms: {}
08-31 10:50:24.042 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-11  INFO water.default: POST /4/sessions, parms: {}
08-31 10:50:24.055 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: POST /99/Rapids, parms: {ast=(setTimeZone "UTC"), session_id=_sid_9a7a}
08-31 10:50:24.468 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-15  INFO water.default: GET /3/Capabilities/API, parms: {}
08-31 10:50:37.122 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  ice Thread  WARN water.default: Unblock allocations; cache below desired, but also OOM: GC CALLBACK, (K/V:Zero   + POJO:198.8 MB + FREE:48.7 MB == MEM_MAX:247.5 MB), desiredKV=30.9 MB OOM!
08-31 10:56:12.695 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-10  INFO water.default: GET /3/Metadata/schemas/CloudV3, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:14.752 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-12  INFO water.default: GET /3/Metadata/schemas/H2OErrorV3, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:16.800 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: GET /3/Metadata/schemas/H2OModelBuilderErrorV3, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:20.892 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-11  INFO water.default: POST /4/sessions, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:21.171 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-12  INFO water.default: GET /flow/index.html, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:21.730 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-25  INFO water.default: GET /flow/fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:21.735 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-12  INFO water.default: GET /flow/fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:21.736 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-15  INFO water.default: GET /flow/fonts/SourceCodePro-Regular.ttf.woff2, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:22.428 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-25  INFO water.default: GET /3/Metadata/endpoints, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:22.761 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-12  INFO water.default: GET /3/NodePersistentStorage/notebook, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:22.783 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: GET /3/NodePersistentStorage/categories/environment/names/clips/exists, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:22.787 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-25  INFO water.default: GET /flow/help/catalog.json, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:22.798 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: GET /3/About, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:22.804 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-12  INFO water.default: GET /3/ModelBuilders, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:22.938 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-11  INFO water.default: POST /99/Rapids, parms: {ast=(setTimeZone "UTC"), session_id=_sid_9257}
08-31 10:56:23.041 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-15  INFO water.default: GET /flow/fonts/fa-regular-400.woff2, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:23.059 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-12  INFO water.default: GET /flow/fonts/Lato-Italic.woff2, parms: {}
08-31 10:56:27.015 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: GET /3/Capabilities/API, parms: {}
08-31 10:57:06.289 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-15  INFO water.default: Reading byte InputStream into Frame:
08-31 10:57:06.290 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-15  INFO water.default:     frameKey:    upload_891ff2a7def056d5c12dba0cc8e04532
08-31 10:57:06.308 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-15  INFO water.default:     totalChunks: 1
08-31 10:57:06.308 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-15  INFO water.default:     totalBytes:  108
08-31 10:57:06.316 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-15  INFO water.default:     Success.
08-31 10:57:08.370 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-11  INFO water.default: POST /3/ParseSetup, parms: {single_quotes=False, source_frames=["upload_891ff2a7def056d5c12dba0cc8e04532"], check_header=1, separator=44}
08-31 10:57:10.584 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: POST /3/Parse, parms: {number_columns=3, source_frames=["upload_891ff2a7def056d5c12dba0cc8e04532"], column_types=["Numeric","Numeric","Numeric"], single_quotes=False, parse_type=CSV, destination_frame=Key_Frame__upload_891ff2a7def056d5c12dba0cc8e04532.hex, column_names=["col1","col2","y"], delete_on_done=True, check_header=1, separator=44, blocking=False, escapechar=0, chunk_size=4194304}
08-31 10:57:10.586 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: Total file size:  108  B
08-31 10:57:10.587 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: Parse chunk size 4194304
08-31 10:57:10.610 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-2-15  INFO water.default: Key upload_891ff2a7def056d5c12dba0cc8e04532 will be parsed using method DistributedParse.
08-31 10:57:10.640 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default: Parse result for Key_Frame__upload_891ff2a7def056d5c12dba0cc8e04532.hex (10 rows, 3 columns):
08-31 10:57:10.648 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default:  ColV2    type          min          max         mean        sigma         NAs constant cardinality
08-31 10:57:10.649 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default:  col1: numeric      2.00000      45.0000      13.3000      16.9316                            
08-31 10:57:10.649 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default:  col2: numeric      1.00000      43.0000      13.1000      14.8881                            
08-31 10:57:10.649 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default:     y: numeric      0.00000      1.00000     0.500000     0.527046                            
08-31 10:57:10.658 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default: Chunk compression summary:
08-31 10:57:10.659 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default:   Chunk Type                 Chunk Name       Count  Count Percentage        Size  Size Percentage
08-31 10:57:10.659 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default:          CBS                     Binary           1          33.333 %       72  B         31.579 %
08-31 10:57:10.659 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default:          C1N  1-Byte Integers (w/o NAs)           2          66.667 %      156  B         68.421 %
08-31 10:57:10.659 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default: Frame distribution summary:
08-31 10:57:10.659 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default:                        Size  Number of Rows  Number of Chunks per Column  Number of Chunks
08-31 10:57:10.659 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default: 127.0.0.1:54321      228  B              10                            1                 3
08-31 10:57:10.659 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default:            mean      228  B       10.000000                     1.000000          3.000000
08-31 10:57:10.659 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default:             min      228  B       10.000000                     1.000000          3.000000
08-31 10:57:10.660 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default:             max      228  B       10.000000                     1.000000          3.000000
08-31 10:57:10.660 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default:          stddev        0  B        0.000000                     0.000000          0.000000
08-31 10:57:10.660 127.0.0.1:54321       20836     FJ-1-15  INFO water.default:           total      228  B              10                            1                 3
08-31 10:57:14.722 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-15  INFO water.default: GET /3/Frames/Key_Frame__upload_891ff2a7def056d5c12dba0cc8e04532.hex, parms: {column_offset=0, full_column_count=-1, row_count=10, row_offset=0, column_count=-1}
08-31 10:57:19.923 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-11  INFO water.default: GET /3/Metadata/schemas/AutoMLV99, parms: {}
08-31 10:57:26.195 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: POST /99/AutoMLBuilder, parms: {}
08-31 10:57:26.221 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: Workflow: Project: AutoML_1_20220831_105726
08-31 10:57:26.226 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: Validation: Setting stopping tolerance adaptively based on the training frame: 0.05
08-31 10:57:26.226 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: Validation: Build control seed: 123
08-31 10:57:26.226 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: DataImport: training frame: Frame key: AutoML_1_20220831_105726_training_Key_Frame__upload_891ff2a7def056d5c12dba0cc8e04532.hex    cols: 3    rows: 10  chunks: 1    size: 228  checksum: -2705803362319216029
08-31 10:57:26.226 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: DataImport: validation frame: NULL
08-31 10:57:26.227 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: DataImport: leaderboard frame: NULL
08-31 10:57:26.227 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: DataImport: blending frame: NULL
08-31 10:57:26.227 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: DataImport: response column: y
08-31 10:57:26.227 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: DataImport: fold column: null
08-31 10:57:26.227 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: DataImport: weights column: null
08-31 10:57:26.234 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  WARN water.default: Workflow: AutoML: XGBoost is not available; skipping it.
08-31 10:57:26.234 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17  INFO water.default: Workflow: Loading execution steps: [{XGBoost : [def_2 (1g, 10w), def_1 (2g, 10w), def_3 (3g, 10w), grid_1 (4g, 90w), lr_search (6g, 30w)]}, {GLM : [def_1 (1g, 10w)]}, {DRF : [def_1 (2g, 10w), XRT (3g, 10w)]}, {GBM : [def_5 (1g, 10w), def_2 (2g, 10w), def_3 (2g, 10w), def_4 (2g, 10w), def_1 (3g, 10w), grid_1 (4g, 60w), lr_annealing (6g, 10w)]}, {DeepLearning : [def_1 (3g, 10w), grid_1 (4g, 30w), grid_2 (5g, 30w), grid_3 (5g, 30w)]}, {completion : [resume_best_grids (10g, 60w)]}, {StackedEnsemble : [best_of_family_1 (1g, 5w), best_of_family_2 (2g, 5w), best_of_family_3 (3g, 5w), best_of_family_4 (4g, 5w), best_of_family_5 (5g, 5w), all_2 (2g, 10w), all_3 (3g, 10w), all_4 (4g, 10w), all_5 (5g, 10w), monotonic (6g, 10w), best_of_family_xgboost (6g, 10w), best_of_family_gbm (6g, 10w), all_xgboost (7g, 10w), all_gbm (7g, 10w), best_of_family_xglm (8g, 10w), all_xglm (8g, 10w), best_of_family (10g, 10w), best_N (10g, 10w)]}]
08-31 10:57:26.235 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17 ERROR water.default: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at water.nbhm.NonBlockingHashMap.putIfMatch(NonBlockingHashMap.java:369) ~[h2o.jar:?]
    at water.nbhm.NonBlockingHashMap.put(NonBlockingHashMap.java:320) ~[h2o.jar:?]
    at ai.h2o.automl.AutoMLSession.getModelingSteps(AutoMLSession.java:76) ~[h2o.jar:?]
    at ai.h2o.automl.ModelingStepsRegistry.getOrderedSteps(ModelingStepsRegistry.java:54) ~[h2o.jar:?]
    at ai.h2o.automl.AutoML.getExecutionPlan(AutoML.java:330) ~[h2o.jar:?]
    at ai.h2o.automl.AutoML.planWork(AutoML.java:359) ~[h2o.jar:?]
    at ai.h2o.automl.AutoML.submit(AutoML.java:395) ~[h2o.jar:?]
    at ai.h2o.automl.AutoML.startAutoML(AutoML.java:80) ~[h2o.jar:?]
    at water.automl.api.AutoMLBuilderHandler.build(AutoMLBuilderHandler.java:15) ~[h2o.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:60) ~[h2o.jar:?]
    at water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:470) [h2o.jar:?]
    at water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:301) [h2o.jar:?]
    at water.api.RequestServer.doPost(RequestServer.java:227) [h2o.jar:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [h2o.jar:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [h2o.jar:?]
    at water.webserver.jetty9.Jetty9ServerAdapter$LoginHandler.handle(Jetty9ServerAdapter.java:130) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762) [h2o.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680) [h2o.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_341]
08-31 10:57:26.242 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17 ERROR water.default: Caught exception: 
08-31 10:57:26.242 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17 ERROR water.default: 
08-31 10:57:26.242 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17 ERROR water.default: ERROR MESSAGE:
08-31 10:57:26.242 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17 ERROR water.default: 
08-31 10:57:26.243 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17 ERROR water.default: Caught exception: java.lang.NullPointerException from: water.nbhm.NonBlockingHashMap.putIfMatch(NonBlockingHashMap.java:369)
08-31 10:57:26.243 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17 ERROR water.default: 
08-31 10:57:26.243 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-17 ERROR water.default: ; Stacktrace: [java.lang.NullPointerException,     water.nbhm.NonBlockingHashMap.putIfMatch(NonBlockingHashMap.java:369),     water.nbhm.NonBlockingHashMap.put(NonBlockingHashMap.java:320),     ai.h2o.automl.AutoMLSession.getModelingSteps(AutoMLSession.java:76),     ai.h2o.automl.ModelingStepsRegistry.getOrderedSteps(ModelingStepsRegistry.java:54),     ai.h2o.automl.AutoML.getExecutionPlan(AutoML.java:330),     ai.h2o.automl.AutoML.planWork(AutoML.java:359),     ai.h2o.automl.AutoML.submit(AutoML.java:395),     ai.h2o.automl.AutoML.startAutoML(AutoML.java:80),     water.automl.api.AutoMLBuilderHandler.build(AutoMLBuilderHandler.java:15),     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method),     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source),     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source),     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source),     water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:60),     water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:470),     water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:301),     water.api.RequestServer.doPost(RequestServer.java:227),     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707),     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790),     org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865),     org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535),     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255),     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317),     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203),     org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473),     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201),     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219),     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144),     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126),     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132),     water.webserver.jetty9.Jetty9ServerAdapter$LoginHandler.handle(Jetty9ServerAdapter.java:130),     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126),     org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132),     org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531),     org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352),     org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260),     org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281),     org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102),     org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118),     org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333),     org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310),     org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168),     org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126),     org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366),     org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762),     org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680),     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)];parms={}
08-31 10:59:11.676 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-10  INFO water.default: GET /3/Logs/nodes/self/files/info, parms: {}
08-31 10:59:11.701 127.0.0.1:54321       20836  0228826-13  INFO water.default: GET /3/Logs/nodes/127.0.0.1:54321/files/info, parms: {}
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is with XGBoost - it's not supported on Windows. Using `H2OAutoML(exclude_algos=["xgboost"])` to skip the XGBoost could help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it could be caused by the small data. Try having at least 200 rows in your dataset. If that won't help, I'd recommend looking into h2o logs (e.g. `h2o.download_all_logs(PATH_TO_A_DIRECTORY)`) and adding the whole stacktrace along with h2o version to this question.